# GitHub overwrote a local file when creating a repository

Tags: git, github

In the process of attempting to make a repository I overwrote the existing contents of the folder where the entire project was contained. This happened when I created the repository in the folder. Is there any way to get the folder contents back or am I just SOL.

Comment: There is small possibility that you still have it if you committed anything. What does `git log --all` show? Any recent commits that might have your content there?

Comment: I'm using the GitHub for Mac application, I can still see the files under unsynced commits, I just can't figure out how to pull them from there.

Comment: Can you use command line git? It would make debugging a lot easier. In console, check what `git status` shows, and look around for your files. If you don't see your files in whenever they should be located, then feel free to checkout to commit that you think contains your stuff using `git checkout <commit_id>` (I guess there is a way to do that in Github GUI as well)

Comment: I tried that in the folder and what I received was

git checkout "Original Push"
error: pathspec 'Original Push' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: commit id cannot be string like "Original Push" (this one is commit message). commit id is funny looking string like `65a0dc...` You can find this id by using `git log`

Comment: Alright, that did it perfectly. Thank you so much. You should put it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: ok, I have added an answer with summary of what have fixed you up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still have your files saved by git if you committed anything.

In console, check what `git status` shows, and look around for your files.
If you don't see your files in whenever they should be located,
then feel free to checkout to commit that you think contains your stuff using

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

Note that `commit_id` is not your commit message like `"Original push"`, but funny looking string like `65a0dc...`

You can find commit id by using `git log` (or `git log --all` if you switched between branches and feel completely lost).